# Maven artifacts cannot be resolved when trying to install to Ubuntu

Tags: java, spring, maven, ubuntu

I am trying to install a project on Ubuntu server but I am receiving the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project db: Could not resolve dependencies for project     com.company.soft.prod:db:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5, mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.26, org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0, org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.5.1-Final, antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6, commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1, dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1, xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2, javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1, org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.5.1-Final, org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.5.1-Final, org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final, cglib:cglib:jar:2.2, asm:asm:jar:3.1, javassist:javassist:jar:3.9.0.GA, org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final, org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE, com.existanze.libraries:orm:jar:0.0.3, joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6.2, com.jolbox:bonecp:jar:0.7.1.RELEASE, com.google.guava:guava:jar:r08: The repository system is offline but the artifact commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5 is not available in the local repository.
```

I have to say that locally I am not facing any problem with dependencies resolution. What I am developing is a mavenized Spring MVC multi-project in Netbeans.
Now that  I am trying to deploy it to the server I receive this error. I tried also mvn clean install -U to update SNAPSHOT but it still does not work. I don't know what else to do, so at this point I need some expert help.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you checked the settings.xml on the server matches that on your local PC?

Comment: Are you trying to _build_ it on the server?

Comment: Yes @his , I am trying to build it on the server.

Comment: Why? Then you need to set up a complete development environment (well, Maven & Java) and need to have the access rights for directories and net access (see @Lan's answer), without any real gain. Building externally (build server or, least favorable, dev's station) and just deploying seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your Ubuntu server does not allow external internet connection to the central repository. Please change the firewall to allow the central repository access. If this is not allowed due to your corporation security policy, you might have to deploy a enterprise maven repository within your corporation.

Comment: To diagnose, you can try something like "wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar", and see if it downloads